# sudo sourcing user's .bashrc without impacting /root/.bashrc or /etc/bashrc

Tags: linux, sudo

Is there any way to make sudo use the user's `.bashrc` file instead of the root one? I would like to use my own `.bashrc` while using sudo instead of the one of root or `/etc/bashrc` (I would have to force other users to use it).

The man page doesn't help much, but I'm sure there is a way to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if that is a very good idea, although I can imagine it to be handy: Inside your sudo environment, you will have the `SUDO_USER` environment variable set to the name of the user who called sudo. That variable can be used in your `/root/.bashrc` to achieve what you want.

Beware, however, that security-wise this can be quite delicate. You should think twice if this cannot somehow be exploited by an untrusted user.

Comment: I would prefer avoiding to modify the /root/.bashrc, but I still can't find any other solution than yours. Ok, then, I will proceed this way. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone googles this and finds it....
Configure your own .bashrc as you like (~/.bashrc)
Then when you need to use sudo, do it like...

sudo -E command

-E tells the superuser to preserve the current environment

Comment: Preserving current environment is not really a good thing to do. There are dozens of things that may go wrong with specially crafted env variables.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, it may be sufficient to set an environment variable in an alias for `sudo`. In my case, I was trying to set a different prompt for when I use `sudo -s` to get a root shell. The following alias in my `.bashrc` seems to work perfectly:

```
alias sudo="PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u@\h:\w\[\e[0m\]\\$ ' sudo "
```